# Why doesn't my Javascript switch statement work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a switch statement and I must be overlooking something, because I don't see why it wouldn't work.

```
$('.handles a').click(function() {
    var li = $(this).parent();

    switch ($(li).data('handle')) {
    case 'minimize':
        $('.window', li).hide();
        break;
    }

    return false;
});
```

Also setup a fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/9aHvx/4/ (click on Min)

It should hide the `.window` div, but it doesn't :(

Comment: Looking to hide a DIV or LIs in a DIV?

Comment: OMG I suck. You all rock. Nevermind. I == stupid. Going to bed now :P Thanks for pointing out the obvious :) *bows his head in shame*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K sorry I wasted your time.

I just made a major boo boo! :P

```
  $('.handles a').click(function() {

    var snippet = $(this).parents('.snippet');

    switch($(this).parent().data('handle')) {
      case 'minimize':
        $('.window', snippet).hide();
        break;
    }

    return false;
  });
```

Thanks all :)

Answer (score 3):

this line `$('.window', li).hide();` is wrong. if you want to target .window and li, you need to write it like you would for css:

```
$('.window, li').hide();
```

Edit: Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9aHvx/7/

Comment: That does something completly different than what he is asking for.

Comment: Nopez. the li is a var. $('.window', li) means .window in li element

Comment: In which case it fails because div.window isn't inside an li.

Comment: Yes, that is right PeeHaa. But do you really think he wants to hide everything and not just the window? (hm.. on second thought you MIGHT be right, but I think he's just looking for a window to hide the element with the window-class)

Comment: I mistook his intention, but either way the li is misplaced.

Comment: Haha, ops. You're the one asking the question, so you probably know what you are asking for :) I thought I was addressing the guy who wrote the answer (shanethehat). Time to go to bed I guess :)

Comment: I know. me 2. I thought i was the first to post comment so I omitted the @shanethehat :P Either way best spent time of my life looking @ wtf it didn't work :P Now off to bed :)

Answer (score 2):

Using the syntax:

```
$('.window', li).hide();
```

means that you search for an element with the class `window`, starting from the node `li`. Objects with the window class that are NOT descendants of `li` will NOT be matched.

In your markup, this is exactly the case. You should skip the second parameter all together. Or, you could rearrange your markup (but that is probably not what you want).

Go for:

```
$('.window').hide();
```

EDIT: This is if you want to hide the window-element only. If you want to hide the li's as well, then goo for shanethehat's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is off

```
$('.handles a').click(function() {
    var li = $(this).parent();
    var x = $(li).data('handle');
    switch (x) {
    case 'minimize':
        alert(x);
        $('.window').hide();
        break;
    }

    return false;
});
```

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/RyanAdriano/9aHvx/10/)

Comment: Hmmmmm.... So I can't use the jquery selector in the switch statement? That's strange or isn't it? Why is that, anyone?

Comment: I mean the $('.window', li) part should have been $('.window, li') sorry if I'm not being clear. I just stored the value into a variable so I can debug it easily using alert.

Answer (score 1):

The `.window` div is not inside the `li` element, so you don't have to pass the `li` variable as parameter:

```
$('.window').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/9aHvx/13/

Use `$('.window').hide();` instead, because there are no `<li>` inside `<div class="window">`